# Im displaying results from a php query and want to display each one in a different slide toggle

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I have got one toggle working which displays the child information but the following toggles don't work and i have no idea how to fix this. I used the code from w3schools to get it working but the other names don't seem to slide down just display them. Any ideas please?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
   <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#flip").click(function(){
     $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css"> 
     #panel,#flip
   {
     padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
     background-color:#e5eecc;
     border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
      }
    #panel
    {
    padding:50px;
   display:none;
   }
   </style>
```

```
    $connect = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1" , "root" , "") or die ("Couldnt connect to database");
    mysql_select_db("travellerfile") or die ("couldnt find the database");

    $searchsurname = $_POST['Surname'];
    $searchfirstname = $_POST['Firstname'];
    $searchage = $_POST['Age'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM child WHERE Surname like '%$searchsurname%' and Firstname like '%$searchfirstname%' and Age like '%$searchage%'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    ?>
    <div id="flip"><?php echo $row['Firstname']; ?> <?php echo $row['Surname']; ?></div>
    <div id="panel"><?php echo $row['DateOfBirth']; ?> <br /> <img src="<?php echo $row['sourcepath']; ?>" width="100px" height="100px"> <form method="post" action="childdetail.php">
                <input name="Button1" type="submit" value="View" /></form>
```

Comment: wheres the code you have already created?

Comment: `_w3schools to get it working_` hmmm.....

Comment: im new this, not sure how to insert the code?

Comment: indent your code by 4 spaces, or post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: ive uploaded code..its not the entire code, but its the only relevant to jquery and php

Answer (score 1):

You can't have duplicate element `id`'s, I'd suggest that you change them to classes instead:

```
<div class="flip"> 
<div class="panel">
```

As for the jQuery, you need to know which `panel` to `slideToggle` on, based on the corresponding `flip`. Given your current structure, you could use the following:-

```
$('.flip').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle('slow'); 
});
```

#### [Here's a simplified example of what you were trying to achieve](http://jsfiddle.net/aX8Vm/1/)

Comment: Implementing your advice has taken away the whole thing all together and just displaying the results in a standard way not with the toggle! I really appreciate your advice and will try anything! feel like pulling my hair out because i know its going to be something simple! :/

Comment: Remember to replace all references to `#panel` and `#flip` for `.panel` and `.flip`